# Setting Cookies in a HTTPModule

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm having problems setting cookies in a custom http module. I'm handling the BeginRequest event and setting the cookie along these lines:

`HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(config.CookieName);`

`SitePrefCookie["key1"] = value1;`

`SitePrefCookie["key2"] = value2;`

`SitePrefCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);`

`SitePrefCookie.Domain = myDomain;`

`SitePrefCookie.Path = "/";`

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(SitePrefCookie);`

I know there's nothing wrong with the cookie itself, because it will work if I call Response.Flush() or set the status to 302 (as it's a http module for redirecting). But I can't do both in one request, i.e. flush and then redirect because ASP.Net will complain about headers already being sent to the client.

I'm sure I can work around this weird limitation, but I just don't understand why the cookie is not even being sent back in the response in a scenario that doesn't require a redirect or flushing of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2666571 for details and a workaround.